# Keeping video file playable while recording to it

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, mp4, h.264

I am trying to stream a file , starting from an arbitrary position , that i am recording to at the same time. But until i stop recording the file seems to be not playable.

Recording

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

Streaming from udp, starting from minute 1.

```
ffmpeg -i  test.mp4 -re -ss 00:01:00 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1453
```

ffmpeg says `moov atom not found` and just quits.
After I stop the recording pipeline. Its works as expected.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The MOOV box is only written once the file's finalized. Mux to .ts instead.

Comment: @Mulvya, Can I store h264 video on that format? And which element do i use as muxer, mpegtsmux?

Comment: @Mulvya, That seems to work, but when I use -t/-ss and -re flags together stream waits whatever seconds I pass to -t/-ss flags and then starts. Is this file extension related?

Comment: The `-re` flag means process in realtime, and the `ss` switch when used as an output option means 'decode and discard till timestamp is reached'. Try putting the ss/t before `-i`

Comment: @Mulvya, that helps with .mp4 files but not with .ts ones

Comment: I would say use mkv container which stores metadata at the beginning (whereas mp4 stores at end) .. hm but when I am thinking of it I am not sure if this precisely true.. maybe give it a shot you will see

Comment: @otopolsky, I found out about that yesterday and yes it works as you expected. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1):

You need to record in fragments to make this work, i.e. setting a reasonable `fragment-duration` (in ms).

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! x264enc ! mp4mux fragment-duration=2000 ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

To play it with gstreamer (while recording):

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this post is outdated, did you tried to use the AVI container. With the avi container I succeed to read the video while it is recording.

Try that for example :

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp_link -c:v h264 -f avi -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -vcodec h264 output.avi
```

But I would be glad to obtain the historic of the comment of your post. It seems that it contains an other potential answer.